# How do I post the row id in a custom built ASP.NET Core Razor Pages editable Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gridview, razor-pages

I have tried several approaches, and as I'm new to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core I'm blocked. Could anybody help me please? It must be something trivial but I googled quite a lot and I can't find a suitable way. I don't want to use jquery or any other javascript library.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<form method="post">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Text 1
            </th>
            <th>
                Text 2
            </th>
            <th>
                Text 3
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.GridRows)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Text1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Text2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Text3)
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
         }
      </tbody>  
 </table>          
 </form>

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var gridRowUpdate = await _context.GridRows.FindAsync(id);

        if (gridRowUpdate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if(await TryUpdateModelAsync<GridRow>(gridRowUpdate, "GridRow", g => g.Text1, g => g.Text2, g => g.Text3))
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Comment: Hi@denki , When you submit the table, You just want  to send the id of each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to click each `save` button to send the Id of that row, You can just follow below simple demo without any jquery or any other javascript library.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Text 1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Text 2
                </th>
                <th>
                    Text 3
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
        @foreach(var item in Model.test)
        {
            <form method="post" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@item.Id" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Text1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Text2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Text3)
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </form>
         }
          
      </tbody>  
 </table>
```